# How to Insert 0 (zero) starting on the 2nd row of output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a small data that is structured like this

File1

```
vol1 10GB 123434
vol2 55GB 231554
vol3 20GB 989765
vol4 17GB 099312
```

File2

```
vol4 server1 099312
vol4 server2 099312
vol4 server3 099312
vol4 server4 099312
```

and the idea is to output data like the following. Assigned the `size` to a variable and insert it to the 1st row and then the rest should be zero.

```
size=`cat file1 |grep 099312 | awk '{print $2}'`


vol4 server1 17GB 099312
vol4 server2  0   099312
vol4 server3  0   099312
vol4 server4  0   099312
```

I'm not really sure if that's the right approach but right now I'm kinda lost.

BTW, file 2 is dynamic and it could be more than 4 rows but the same objective.. `size` should only be applied/inserted on the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
               {print $1,$2,a[$1],$3; 
                a[$1]=0}' file{1,2} | column -t

vol4  server1  17GB  099312
vol4  server2  0     099312
vol4  server3  0     099312
vol4  server4  0     099312
```

centering "0" will require additional formatting, not sure it was required.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { vols[$1]=$2; next }
     { if ($1 in vols) {
         print $1, $2, vols[$1], $3
         delete vols[$1]
       } else {
         print $1, $2, "0", $3
       }
     }' file1 file2
```